# JOLT Transform Json Array while maintaining the Array structure

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I have an Array of Jsons and I want to transform the keys of individual Jsons while still maintaining the Array.

```
[
  {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2"
  },
  {
    "a": "one",
    "b": "two"
  }
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
  {
    "my_a": "1",
    "my_b": "2"
  },
  {
    "my_a": "one",
    "my_b": "two"
  }
]
```

JOLT Spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "a": "my_a",
        "b": "my_b"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

However, I see this:

```
{
  "my_a" : [ "1", "one" ],
  "my_b" : [ "2", "two" ]
}
```

I see that the transformation is applied but the output is not what I expect.

Anyone who has faced similar problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include array index `[&1]` while changing the name

**Try with below Jolt Spec:**

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { 
        "a": "[&1].my_a",
        "b": "[&1].my_b"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Validating the Spec:**

[image]